# How can I execute all sql files' sql commands into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, windows

[image]

such as one of the file content is:

```
INSERT INTO `de_admin` VALUES('1','10','admin','f297a57a5a743894a0a4','admin','','','','1547032874','127.0.0.1');
```

I want to know how can I execute all these files' sql commands into my MySQL database?

I mean is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: This is Windows Server 2008.

Comment: You may need to write a batch file or, if available, PowerShell script unless you have other options (e.g. Python, NodeJS, even C#) as there's no way to do this without automation of some kind. One hacky alternative is to concatenate them all to one file and run that.